# Suppress print line breaks in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am learning Fortran, and I have made this program in order to learn how to handle strings:

```
program use_strings
   character(100) :: theStr
   integer :: strLen
   theStr = "THIS IS A NICE LITTLE STRING!"
   strLen = len_trim(theStr)
   print *, "This is the len_trim of the string ", theStr, ": " ,strLen
end program use_strings
```

**The output I expected was:**

This is the len_trim of the string THIS IS A NICE LITTLE STRING!: 29

**But instead I get this:**

This is the len_trim of the string
THIS IS A NICE LITTLE STRING!
"TAB(s?)" : "TAB(s?)" 29

**Question**
Not that the 'TAB(s?)' denotes that there were tabs printed in the terminal. So, my humble question: How do I get the printout on one line in the terminal?

Comment: »Read a tutorial about output formatting. Tre are many questions here about this topic, probavly including exact duplocates.

Comment: You may also want to look at the documentation for the `trim` function.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844250/output-formatting-too-much-whitespace-in-gfortran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062619/write-statement-without-a-lot-of-spaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813340/integer-output-formatting-with-print-statement/11814170#11814170 and many others. Have you read them?

Comment: For `trim` for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610737/way-fortran-handles-empty-spaces/17610920#17610920